# Is it possible to run Firebird 2.5 query in parallel mode?

Tags: query-optimization, firebird, firebird2.5

Colleagues, i have a query which looks like

```
FOR select first 100 contracts.doc from TABLE_1
 INTO :contr 
 DO
  BEGIN
  insert into tmp_port (
        DT,
        ....)

        select
            :IN$DT as DT,
            ...
        from p_procedure (0,  :contr , :IN$DT);

  END
```

The problem is that proprietary procedure `p_procedure` works very slow. I can't optimize `p_procedure`.

In Oracle, as I remember, I can increase the speed of execution using `parallel`.

Is there something similar (like hint 'parallel') in FireBird 2.5?
Is there any other approaches to increase the execution speed? 
Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Firebird doesn't have a parallel execution mode. Could you post what `p_procedure` does? Maybe there is something to improve there.

Comment: Mark, does any version of FireBird can't ececute query in parallel mode? May be FireBird 3.0? Unfortunatly. I can't post 'p_procedure' because it is protected by copyright. =(

Comment: No, Firebird doesn't have a parallel execution mode; that includes Firebird 3.

Comment: Mark, may i ask you one more question?

My idea is: 
1. Put `contracts.doc` into any type of Java Collection.
2. Split collection into 100 parts.
2. Call 'p_procedure' separate in 100 threads from Java Code.

What do you think about this approach?
Is there any limitation for number of threads connected to FireBird 2.5 DB?  

Thank you.

Comment: Firebird 2.5 on Windows has a 1024 (or 2048) connection limit, however more threads don't always mean more throughput (especially not if you use SuperServer, as in Firebird 2.5 and earlier that essentially processes one connection at a time). I'd start with 2 to 4 threads, and **test** if scaling up the number of threads actually improves throughput.